# How do I remove a rust stain on my bathroom vanity counter?

Tags: bathroom, rust-removal, vanity, countertops

We just moved into a rental home and I seem to have done something stupid. I have a metal plate that I made into a make holder that I spray painted gold on the sink counter top. I must have gotten wet and left this ring on the top. I've tried bleach, Coca Cola, Mean Green cleaner, but nothing seems to make it better.

Please tell me you guys have ideas. I really need this off!

Comment: Try letting the bleach set for an hour or so, if you haven't already. Also you can try CLR (Calcium, Lime, Rust) remover.

Comment: Whink is another product that will get it out. Read the directions though, it is some strong stuff. it will eat the porcelain it not treated with the proper attention.

Comment: If you're very careful, you can try some muriatic acid, available from the big box hardware stores.  Some safety tips: Always wear eye protection and long rubber gloves.  Do not breath the stuff in.  It must be diluted. Never add water to the acid, always add the acid to water.  Do not pour down the drain as it will eat your pipes. Keep several pounds of baking soda on hand to neutralize the acid.  As with any strong cleaner, you should do a small test first. Muriatic acid is great for Corian.

Comment: I've had success with a Mr. Clean Magic Eraser before. I'm not sure how it will affect your counter top though.

Answer (score 3):

I presume the sink is faux marble.  Try Lime Away.  Or C.L.R. - they should remove it without hurting the surface.

Comet bathroom cleaner (The squirt kind) works good on light rust spots, but would take a while on really severe spots.

Answer (score 0):

Bar keeper's Friend will remove the rust stain. You can find it in the cleaning aisle, near products like Comet.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? Do you have experience to invalidate this answer?